# Read table using variable in the directory

Tags: r, read.table

I'm looking to read in a table.txt from a specific directory. I'd like to assign parts of that directory to a variable.

Without the variable:

```
asv.table <- read.table("/home/jbuser/Uganda/asv.Uganda.txt", sep="\t",row.names = TRUE, header=TRUE)
```

With the variable:

```
Region = "Uganda"
asv.table <- read.table(paste("/home/jbuser/",Region,"/asv.",Region,".txt", sep=""),row.names = TRUE, header=TRUE)
```

But my code just stalls out and returns nothing even after several minutes.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `paste0` instead of `paste` to avoid having empty spaces in the output.

Comment: You can also `read.table(sprintf("/home/jbuser/%s/asv.%s.txt", Region, Region))`. function `file.path` is also useful to put together file paths.

Comment: *"stalls out and returns nothing"* seems unlikely, I've never (in 12+ years in R) seen it do that with `read.table`: it has always (for me) returned a table, emitted an error (and returned nothing), emit a warning (and return bad data, likely a bad argument on my part), or "stall" while it's allocating too much memory (very large file) and either emit an error about memory limitations or eventually return the (very large) frame. If there are warnings or errors, please include the literal text in your question.

Comment: Can you try reading in just a handful of rows first? Such as `asv.table <- read.table(paste0("/home/jbuser/",Region,"/asv.",Region,".txt"),row.names = TRUE, header=TRUE, nrows=10)`, see if that returns "normally". If that works, then try a larger number of rows until you find the problem and have a better idea where in the file problems start. (I have seen embedded nulls or embedded unicode occasionally throw off `read.table`, though never silently.)